# eosio-cpp command not found error?

Tags: smart-contract

When I am trying to run hello world smart contract using a command

`eosio-cpp -abigen -o hello.wasm hello.cpp`

shown an error `eosio-cpp: command not found`?

Comment: Which version of `eosio.cdt` and `eos` are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a proper installation of the CDT like in this link https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/installing-the-contract-development-toolkit ?

Maybe you dont have put the read write permission, try

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/bin
```

or if you use a previous version:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/eosio-cpp
```